# Call data from a specific column in a data frame using a object

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to call data to a new data frame based on objects specifying a column in a data frame.

Here is a reproducible example, showing that I cannot achieve the aimed result:

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame('first' = seq(1:5),
                         'second' = letters[seq(1:5)])

specifcdata1 <- 'dataframe1[first]'                         
specifcdata2 <- 'dataframe1$second'

dataframe2 <- data.frame('Specific 1' = tail(specifcdata1, 1),
                         'Specific 2' = tail(specifcdata2, 1))
```

Resulting in:

```
> dataframe2
        Specific.1       Specific.2
1 dataframe1[first] dataframe1$second
```

The aimed result is:

```
> dataframe2
  Specific.1 Specific.2
1          5          e
```

Considering `dataframe1`,

```
> dataframe1
  first second
1     1      a
2     2      b
3     3      c
4     4      d
5     5      e
```

**QUESTION: How can we call the object (data, not the stored characters)?**

Comment: What about `last(dataframe1[["first"]])`? `'dataframe1[first]'` is an invalid R expression, because `first` is a data variable and not an env variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the combination of `parse()` and `eval()`. I also added quotation marks in `'dataframe1["first"]'` or else in would not have worked.

```r
dataframe1 <- data.frame('first' = seq(1:5),
                         'second' = letters[seq(1:5)])

specifcdata1 <- 'dataframe1["first"]'                         
specifcdata2 <- 'dataframe1$second'

dataframe2 <- data.frame('Specific 1' = tail(eval(parse(text = specifcdata1)), 1),
                         'Specific 2' = tail(eval(parse(text = specifcdata2)), 1))

dataframe2
#>   first Specific.2
#> 5     5          e
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: +1. If @bttomio wants the first column to be named `Specific.1` rather than `first`, then use double brackets instead — ie, `dataframe1[["first"]]` rather than `dataframe1["first"]`.